# Will installing OS X Mavericks over Mavericks Developer Preview erase data?

Tags: macos

I am running OS X Developer Preview right now and I want to know If I install the full Mavericks from Mac App store if it will just be an update or a fresh install.

In short I just want to make sure none of my apps or data is effected. Is it safe to upgrade through the app store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed mavericks on my macbook air. It was a 40 minute update and made no changes to my 3rd party apps, nor did it erase any of my mac app data.

Best of luck!
-e